# It make error message.what does it make?

Tags: python-2.7

```
from sys import argv

from os.path import exists

script,from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" %(from_file, to_file)

in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exists? %r" % exists(to_file)

print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file,'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print"Alright, all done."

to_file.close()
from_file.close()
```

after execution it makes error message

to_file.close()
ArrtibuteError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

Comment: `to_file` is a string from argv, not a file object, so that you can't close it should be no surprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be closing the file descriptors not the file names.

Replace:

```
to_file.close()
from_file.close()
```

with:

```
in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```